# Why is the range() function slower than a combination of min and max?

Tags: r, performance, range, max, min

I came across R's `range` function. It is for sure a useful tool and makes code more readable, but its speed can be doubled by replacing it with a simple one-liner including `min` and `max`.

I did some benchmarks and the 'bad' performance of the range function surprised me. For comparison I wrote a function called `range2` which uses min and max (see code). Except for speed, are there any reasons why this function exists if it can be outperformed by a simple one-liner, which is also easily readable?

```
require(microbenchmark)

range2 <- function(x) c(min(x),max(x))  

n <- 1000000
x <- rnorm(n)
microbenchmark(range(x), range2(x))
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
# range(x) 4.696101 4.734751 5.321603 4.796301 4.814751 23.0646   100   b
#range2(x) 2.477602 2.516101 2.542540 2.535051 2.544052  3.7636   100  a 

n <- 10000000
x <- rnorm(n)
microbenchmark(range(x), range2(x))
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# range(x) 47.3246 47.9498 58.27992 55.25795 61.98205 146.5100   100   b
#range2(x) 24.7063 25.5021 25.59192 25.55245 25.63515  27.1088   100  a
```

For sure this would be not the first bottleneck one wants to get rid of, since we are talking about milliseconds on a vector with 10,000,000 entries, but I expected `range` to be faster. My simple intuition was:

`range` goes through the data one time and searches for the minimum and maximum at the same time, whereas my `range2` function goes through the data two times: One time to find the minimum and one time to find the maximum.

Maybe someone can give some background about the implementation. Maybe the reason is that `min` and `max` are implemented in C and `range` is not?

Addition: 
I've already talked about that with a friend of mine and he just made this function faster by implementing it in C++ via:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <float.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector range3(NumericVector x) {
  int xs = x.size();
  double minValue = FLT_MAX;
  double maxValue = FLT_MIN;
  for (int i =0; i < xs; i++) {
    if (x[i] < minValue) minValue = x[i];
    if (x[i] > maxValue) maxValue = x[i];
  }
  Rcpp::NumericVector result(2);
  result[0] = minValue;
  result[1] = maxValue;
  return result;
}
```

and this gives the following benchmarks:

```
n <- 10000000
x <- rnorm(n)
microbenchmark(range(x), range2(x) ,range3(x))
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval cld
#  range(x) 47.8583 48.30355 58.12575 55.3135 62.10295 149.9648   100   c
# range2(x) 24.8211 25.53615 25.90920 25.6176 25.79175  42.4659   100  b 
# range3(x) 13.2458 13.30385 13.47175 13.3797 13.65410  14.3487   100 a
```

Comment: You can see from `range.default` that it does a few extra checks before calling `c(min(x), max(x))` itself. It's not optimized for speed. It's just a user friendly function. It seems unlikely that those millisecond differences would be the source a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Hi, here is how you view the sourse code of `range.default`: `getAnywhere(range.default)`

Comment: The function definition should also display if you just run the line `range.default`

Comment: Thank you for the answers. This is just a nice example that some knowledge about the data you are working with is helpful, since you can avoid checks which are not needed.

Comment: I have *no* idea about R, but a wild guess: The internal `x[i]<minValue` and `x[i]>maxValue` checks will yield `true` only for the first few data elements. After that, only "outliers" will yield `true`. So I would be interested to see a comparison on these functions based on data that is 1. constant, 2. ascending, 3. descending (yeah, we can hear the words "branch prediction fail" sneaking in here...)

Comment: @MrFlick please put your comment into answer, it is highly voted, still unanswered, question. Worth to have it marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the source for `range.default` (run R 3.6.1)

```
 > range.default
function (..., na.rm = FALSE, finite = FALSE) 
{
    x <- c(..., recursive = TRUE)
    if (is.numeric(x)) {
        if (finite) 
            x <- x[is.finite(x)]
        else if (na.rm) 
            x <- x[!is.na(x)]
        c(min(x), max(x))
    }
    else {
        if (finite) 
            na.rm <- TRUE
        c(min(x, na.rm = na.rm), max(x, na.rm = na.rm))
    }
}
```

You can see that it does a few extra checks before calling `c(min(x), max(x))` itself. It's not optimized for speed. It's just a user friendly function. It seems unlikely that those millisecond differences would be the source a performance bottleneck.